# Why does TypeScript not automatically use literal types when inferring the return type of a function?

Tags: typescript

Considering the following snippets:

```js
//
// Case 1: return type is { statusCode: number }
//
export const handler = () => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200
  }
}

//
// Case 2: return type is { statusCode: 200 }
//
export const handler = () => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200 as const
  }
}
```

Since the function will always return the same value (no alternative flows), it seems to me the second case should be the default. Or, in other words, I think TypeScript should always try to be as specific as possible by default.

Why do I need to manually specify the return type, or use `as const`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field `statusCode` is mutable on the returned object. Thus, if changed, the type would no longer be the same which breaks type safety.

```
let obj = handler();
obj.statusCode = 404; // This is allowed but breaks the type { statusCode: 200 }
```

Comment: This sounds like a good reason, but the same can be observed if the return value is `function() { return 200; }`; the 200 in this function clearly can't be changed, but the type will be inferred as `() => number` and not `() => 200`.

Comment: @kaya3 It follows the same logic. When the function is invoked, it returns a number that when stored later can be changed. There is no guarantee from the function that the value returned is immutable if not specified explicitly.

Comment: Functions are always immutable - at least, it is not possible to change the code that a function runs when you call it, though you can change its properties like any other object. Reassigning a variable so that it references a different object is not the same as mutating an object.

Comment: This is correct, but the number returned from the function is not.

Comment: I'm saying if the return value *is* the function. But numbers are immutable; if they weren't, you'd be able to change the number 200 itself so that it was some other number, then other references to 200 would now be references to that other number.

Comment: I should have used a simpler example, like the one kaya3 used. I can understand the reasoning @Playturbo, but doing `() => 200` does also return a non-literal type. In my example, the function returns a mutable object. In kaya's example, the function returns a number. It cannot be mutated. What could be mutated, is the variable that the caller uses to store the function's return value. But the value itself, being a primitive, won't be mutated. So I'm not following your reasoning there...

Comment: If I do `const fn = () => 200; let status = fn();`, I will get status type to be `number`. I would expect to be `200`. So if later in the code I do `status = 300;` I would expect a compilation error, since status is a literal type `200` (due to TypeScript inference, it would have been the same as writing `let status: 200 = fn();`. But as we know, this is not currently the case, so my question remains... why does it work like that? :)

Comment: That would be because the literal `200` is itself of type number. If it worked like you are suggesting, `let num = 5; num = 3;` would not be possible as `typeof num` would be `"5"`. We would then lose the ability to edit numbers.